# Using LocalNotificationSchedule and Firebase Notfication in same React native app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to use both localNotificationSchedule and Firebase Remote Push Notification in a React Native app at the same time?
Using the common library on https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification says that the AndroidManifest.xml needs two different services

```
<!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
    <service
        android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerServiceGcm"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- </ Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->

    <!-- < Else > -->
    <service
        android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- </Else> -->
```

So do I have to choose either of them?

Answer (score 0):

I am using OneSignal myself, but I can tell you you need to add both if you want to use local notifications.

Also, GCM will be deprecated in a few weeks so you don't want to use that one. Just use FCM from Firebase.